# How do I get data from a table and display it in another table in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, jtable, swap

How do I get data from a table and display it in another table in Java?
I select a row from a table and get its values but I don't know how to display it another table.

Comment: post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Netbean Project that copies data from one table to another
Hope this helps.

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author razak
 */
public class CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable
     */
    public CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable() {

        initComponents();
        populateTableToCopyFrom();


    }

    /**
     * This populates tableToCopyDataFrom with test data 
     */
    private void populateTableToCopyFrom() {
        String [] columnName = {"Name","Age"};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnName,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            String temp[] = {"Student " + i, (i+ 1)* 10+ ""};
            tableModel.addRow(temp);
        }
        tableToCopyDataFrom.setModel(tableModel);
    }

    /**
     * This methods copies values from tableToCopyDataFrom to  tableToCopyDataTo
     */
    private void copyDataToTableFromTable(){
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)tableToCopyDataFrom.getModel();
        tableToCopyDataTo.setModel(tableModel);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tableToCopyDataFrom = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tableToCopyDataTo = new javax.swing.JTable();
        copyToTableButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tableToCopyDataFrom.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tableToCopyDataFrom);

        tableToCopyDataTo.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(tableToCopyDataTo);

        copyToTableButton.setText("Copy To Table below");
        copyToTableButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                copyToTableButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 375, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(copyToTableButton)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(copyToTableButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 145, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(51, 51, 51))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * Button click that copies data to the second table
     * @param evt event listener
     */
    private void copyToTableButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        copyDataToTableFromTable();
    }                                                 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CopyDataFromTableToAnotherTable().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton copyToTableButton;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable tableToCopyDataFrom;
    private javax.swing.JTable tableToCopyDataTo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```